# Joomla(1.5) templates wont appear on the interface when i add add the folder in the /teplates directory

Tags: templates, installation, joomla

I tried installing via the interface but it said that the package i waas trying to install wasnt found.
I also tried puting the extracted folder in the templates/ folder but still nothing.
I tried reinstalling Joomla all over again but with no luck.
I am suspecting that the problem has something to do with mysql but i cannot confirm that...

Note that the server is running on my laptop
thank you

Comment: I should also add that adding or removing one of the existing templates(eg beez) has the expected results(if the folder is there there is a corresponding menu item, if not there is no item)...

Answer (score 0):

The custom template you are setting up requires a correct .xml file. and also the correct naming. you can always copy the xml file from an existing template and update it with your template name. update the files and folders that are included.

Here is a basic xml file i use and update all the data in to (name is templateDetails.xml and make sure you have the cap D and all the rest in lowercase) Other than the xml file the rest isnt required. you could have nothing but the xml file and you should still see it in the joomla template interface.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<install version="1.5" type="template">
    <name>GDW Template</name>
    <creationDate>Juin 2010</creationDate>
    <author>Geant du Web</author>
    <copyright>Geant du Web</copyright>
    <authorEmail>info@geantduweb.ca</authorEmail>
    <authorUrl>www.geantduweb.ca</authorUrl>
    <version>1.2</version>
    <description>Ne pas copier sans autorisation ecrite du Geant du Web</description>
    <files>
        <filename>component.php</filename>
        <filename>favicon.ico</filename>
        <filename>index.html</filename>
        <filename>index.php</filename>
        <filename>templatetools_1.5.php</filename>
        <filename>vars_1.5.php</filename>
        <filename>params.ini</filename>
        <filename>template_thumbnail.png</filename>
        <folder>html</folder>
        <folder>images</folder>
        <folder>css</folder>
        <folder>js</folder>
    </files>
    <languages>
    </languages>
    <administration>
    <languages>
        </languages>
  </administration>
    <positions>
        <position>breadcrumbs</position>
        <position>banner</position>
        <position>left</position>
        <position>right</position>
        <position>top</position>
        <position>bottom</position>
        <position>slideshow</position>
        <position>language</position>
        <position>topmenu</position>
        <position>mc-right</position>
        <position>mc-left</position>
        <position>o-comp</position>
        <position>u-comp</position>
        <position>footer</position>     
        <position>footm</position>  
        <position>user1</position>  
        <position>user2</position>
        <position>user3</position>
        <position>user4</position>
        <position>user5</position>
        <position>user6</position>
        <position>user7</position>
        <position>user8</position>
        <position>user9</position>
    </positions>
</install>
```